# How do I email an invoice using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html-email

I am developing a website that contains a store, the store is coded in JavaScript (VanillaCartJS) and I have the user paying with PayPal. I was hoping that PayPal would tell the user what item and how much they ordered but I was only able to get it to charge them the correct amount.

The JS file is called cart.js and the function that adds the items to the cart is:

```js
function insertItemToDOM(product) {
    cartDOM.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div class="cart__item">
      <img class="cart__item__image" src="${product.image}" alt="${product.name}">
      <h3 class="cart__item__name">${product.name}</h3>
      <h3 class="cart__item__price">${product.price}</h3>
      <button class="btn btn--primary btn--small${(product.quantity === 1 ? ' btn--danger' : '')}" data-action="DECREASE_ITEM">&minus;</button>
      <h3 class="cart__item__quantity">${product.quantity}</h3>
      <button class="btn btn--primary btn--small" data-action="INCREASE_ITEM">&plus;</button>
      <button class="btn btn--danger btn--small" data-action="REMOVE_ITEM">&times;</button>
    </div>
  `);

    addCartFooter();
}
```

I also save the cart to local storage and I am thinking if I can save it, I could email it to the customer as well, the code for this is as well as the function 'countCartTotal()':

```js
function countCartTotal() {
    let cartTotal = 0;
    cart.forEach(cartItem => cartTotal += cartItem.quantity * cartItem.price);
    document.querySelector('[data-action="CHECKOUT"]').innerText = `Pay $${cartTotal}`;
    return cartTotal;
}

function saveCart() {
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    countCartTotal();
}
```

I have a forgot password system that uses the PHP mailing service is it possible to run JS code in this email and if so how would I do it?

Comment: you mean you want to run jaavscript when user opens your mail in his E-mail account ?

Comment: Why not create the invoice and email it via PHP?

Comment: @BrightFaith no I want to email a user a copy of their shopping cart so that know what items they bought etc

Comment: @devlincarnate That could work, would you be able to advise me on how to go about this?

Comment: @RossCurrie php has  [mail function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)  , send your data to back-end via `ajax` and handle your mail in the back-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a couple of options you can use:

- Sending email using an smtp server like authsmtp (paied)
- Sending an email using an api service like mailgun (paied)
- Sending am email using amazon SES
- Sending an email using your own server using sendmail, mail.. (requires more configuration)

In many cases when using shared hosting the mail server is already configured and available, so you can use the `mail` function in php to send your email, but first before putting it to production you need to make sure that the emails are not sent to the spam folder, if so use authsmtp as its easy to setup (may require PHPMailer).

The process that is needed will look like this:

**Send the request from the frontend (Javascript Ajax or HTML)**

*Javascript Ajax (jQuery)*

```
$.post("/sendmail", { to: "abcd@gmail.com" })
```

*Or using html form*

```
<form action="/sendmail" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="to" />
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

**On your php backend using `mail`** may require smtp/sendmail to be installed on your server *usually the case with shared hosting* function:

```
$to = $_POST["to"];

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  mail($to, "SUBJECT", "CONTENT OF THE EMAIL");
}
```

*Using authsmtp service with PHPMailer*

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "mail.authsmtp.com";
$mail->Port = 2525;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = ''; // To enable TLS/SSL encryption change to 'tls'
$mail->AuthType = "CRAM-MD5";
$mail->Username = "USERNAME";
$mail->Password = "PASSWORD";
$mail->setFrom('YOU@YOUR-DOMAIN-NAME.COM', 'YOUR NAME');
$mail->addReplyTo('YOU@YOUR-DOMAIN-NAME.COM', 'YOUR NAME');
$mail->addAddress('YOU@YOUR-DOMAIN-NAME.COM', 'YOUR NAME'); //(Send the test to yourself)
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```